# How does Express.js handle Cache-Control automatically?

Tags: node.js, express, cache-control

I was going to use a 'cache buster' to add a hash to the end of static js and css files during grunt build. I don't know too much about cache control. Without doing anything Express.js was sending a 304 status code. If I modified the file then Express.js would send the new file. It seems like I don't need to do anything and it works as expected.

Do I need to implement Cache-Control? Is it already handled auto magically?

Comment: Assuming you don't want a `max-age: 0` on your static content, you're still going to need a cache buster, or requests will never make it to your server in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, express handles cache-control automatically. It's default value is set to true. And you can just handle it by increasing/decreasing it's `maxAge` property value. (`in milliseconds`). Or you can turn this option `on` or `off` by setting `cacheControl to true or false` .

For more Reference you can refer : **[Express Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)**